# Python class self variables being overwritten

Tags: python, class, overwrite

I'm making a recursive tic tac toe search player, and have an object called board which I create every time I simulate a new board. However, the original board is being overwritten by future boards. I'm not sure how this happens.

I have the code that matters below. What happens is this:
I start the ai player and call getMove(), which should return a single number.
In getMove, I start a recursive ai, which on initiation starts to build an array of every board state. The list is global, so build frontier doesn't return anything. It only says "if this is an end state, x/o/tie, then add it to the list. Otherwise, make a new ai player that has this spot filled and check for end state, on and on etc. No where does it reference the aiPlayer.board, yet somehow it is overwriting.

When having the ai.getMove return a random move, (just a quick thing that finds all spots in the board and returns a random one out of those spots) the line

```
print("the game board this sees")
    self.board.printBoard()
```

prints the board that was input when I first called the ai player. If I mark a spot, and then call the ai to decide the next spot, this print function prints the board after I mark a spot but before it is filled. This is good.

however, when using the actual algorithm, the same line prints a filled board. I never touch the ai's self.board object to change it, I only make copies of the c_board object and build iterations off of that.

My question is: even though I never touch the self.board, why is it being overwritten? are the c_boards that I make later one pointers to the same original board? What is going on?
(PS. sorry for calling it an ai, it is just a brute force attempt. I'm trying to see how I think through and implement it without any tutorials of other people's approaches.{but I have looked for solutions for why the code is buggy, my first answer wasn't turning to this forum. Thank you for helping!})

```
    global overallFrontier
    overallFrontier = []
    
    class aiPlayer:
      def __init__(self, field, currentTurn,firstPlayer,width,path,aiMode):
        self.board = c_board(False,field,width,path,currentTurn) # <-- this board is getting overwritten
        self.mode = aiMode
        self.firstPlayer = firstPlayer
    
        overallFrontier = []
   

     def getMove(self):
           
            self.bestTileNum = self.smartSearchGetMove()
            print("getMove: ", self.bestTileNum)
            print("the game board this sees")
            self.board.printBoard() # <-- When I print this, I don't see the original board.
        #instead, I see a hypothetical board created later
            #return 
            return self.bestTileNum #int
   

     def smartSearchGetMove(self): 
                recurse_buildFrontier(self.board.field,self.board.width,self.board.path,self.board.currentTurn,0)
          return bestNumber #any number 1-9, the implementation isn't where my issue is
#Sorry about the weird indenting, I can't hit tab. The actual code  # lines up properly
        
    
   

 class recurse_buildFrontier:
          def __init__(self,field,width,path,currentTurn,iteration):
            print("RecurseAI: ", iteration)
            self.board = c_board(False,field,width,path,currentTurn)
            self.iteration = iteration
            self.buildFrontier()
          def buildFrontier(self):  
            print("================ BuildFrontierCall =====================")
            print("iteration: ", self.iteration + 1)
            print("frontier: ", overallFrontier)
        
            for row in self.board.field:
              for spot in row:
                if(spot in range(1,11) and spot not in self.board.path):#the not path bit is implied, just for clarity its written
                  spotFrontierBoard = c_board(False,self.board.field,self.board.width,self.board.path,not self.board.currentTurn)
                  spotFrontierBoard.fillBoard(spot)
                  
                  print("-- spot: ", spot)
                  print("! spotFrontierBoard print !")
                  spotFrontierBoard.printBoard()
                  print("! self board print !")
                  self.board.printBoard()
        
                  spotFrontierBoard.evaluatePosition()
                  evaluate = spotFrontierBoard.winState
                  evaluatePrinter = "X" if evaluate == c_board.winType["x"] else "O" if evaluate == c_board.winType["o"] else "TIE" if evaluate == c_board.winType["tie"] else "none" if evaluate == c_board.winType["none"] else "evaluate error"
                  print("evaluate: ",evaluatePrinter )
                  if (evaluate in [c_board.winType["x"],c_board.winType["o"],c_board.winType["tie"]]):
                    overallFrontier.append(spotFrontierBoard)
                  else:
                    recurse_buildFrontier(spotFrontierBoard.field,self.board.width,spotFrontierBoard.path,not self.board.currentTurn,self.iteration+1).buildFrontier()
        
            print("++++++++++ END BuildFrontierCall +++++++++++")
```

The code for the c_board class is:

```
from math import trunc

global boardWidth 
boardWidth = 0

class c_board:
  firstPlayer = True  
  winType = {
      "x": 0,
      "tie": 2,
      "o": 4,
      "none": -2,
    }#first player win type
  def __init__(self,isNewField,ifNewFieldThisIsEmptyListElseThisIsBoardField,widthZEROIfNewBoard,path,newTurnNumber):
    
    self.path = path
    self.currentTurn = newTurnNumber #not lastTurn
    boardWidth = widthZEROIfNewBoard
    
    if boardWidth == 0:
      self.width = self._getBoardSize()
    else:
      self.width = boardWidth
      
    if isNewField:
      self.field = self.newField()
    else:
      self.field = ifNewFieldThisIsEmptyListElseThisIsBoardField
   
    self.winState = self.evaluatePosition()
  
  def printBoard(self):
    spotNum = 1
    for column in self.field:
      line = ""
      spotNum = 1
      for val in column:
        if(val == "x" or val == "o"):
          val = val.upper()
        line += str(val)
        if(spotNum  != 3):
          line += " | "
        spotNum +=1
      print("  ",line)
    print("path: ",self.path)


  def evaluatePosition(self):
    #returns either 0 1 or 2 depending on the winType(loose tie or win) 
    hitNum = False
    for i in self.field:
      for j in i:
        for k in range(self.width * self.width):
          if (str(j) == str(k)):
            hitNum = True

    #          x1 x2 x3  o1 o2 o3
    downXO = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    for column in self.field:
      #count accross
      
      if(column.count("x") == self.width):
        print("x, accross")
        self.winState = self.winType["x"]  
        return self.winState
      
      elif(column.count("o") == self.width):
        print("o, accross")
        self.winState = self.winType["o"]
        return self.winState
     
      for i in range(self.width):
        if (column[i] == "x" or column[i] == "o"):
          #count down
          xo = 0 if (column[i] == "x") else 1
          downXO[xo][i] += 1
          #down win
          if (downXO[xo][i] == self.width):
            if(not bool(xo) == self.currentTurn): #In xo, 0 is x, whereas everywhere else True(num>0) is x
              print("down x")
              self.winState = self.winType["x"]   
              return self.winState
            else:
              print("down o")
              self.winState = self.winType["o"]
              return self.winState

    #count diagonal tl to br
    centerTile = self.field[trunc(self.width / 2)][trunc(self.width / 2)]
    if (str(centerTile) not in [
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"
    ]):  #TODO: make this a loop iterable generated by the boardsize
      xo = 0 if (centerTile == "x") else 1

      #this first i loop section does top left to bottom right, as x and y positions are the same number in this order
      Lxo = [0, 0]
      for i in range(self.width):
        if (
            Lxo[0] > 0 and Lxo[1] > 0
        ):  #if the diagonal is already not pure, aka there are both x and o on the diagonal
          break
        if (self.field[i][i] == centerTile):
          Lxo[xo] += 1
          if (Lxo[xo] == self.width):
            if(not bool(xo) == self.currentTurn):
              print("tl acc x")
              self.winState = self.winType["x"]
              return self.winState
            else:
              print("tl acc o")
              self.winState = self.winType["o"]
              return self.winState

      Rxo = [0, 0]
      rlistCoords = list(zip(range(self.width), range(self.width - 1, -1, -1)))
      for item in rlistCoords:
        if (self.field[item[0]][item[1]] == centerTile):
          Rxo[xo] += 1
        if (Rxo[xo] == self.width):
          if(not bool(xo) == self.currentTurn):
            self.winState = self.winType["x"]
            return self.winState
          else:
            self.winState = self.winType["o"]
            return self.winState
    if (hitNum == False):
      self.winState = self.winType["tie"]
      return self.winState
    self.winState = self.winType["none"]
    return self.winState
    
  def fillBoard(self,tile):

    i = 0
    j = 0
    for column in self.field:
      for val in column:
        if (val == tile):
          self.field[i][j] = ("x" if (self.currentTurn == self.firstPlayer) else "o")
          self.currentTurn = not self.currentTurn
          self.path.append(tile)
          return self.field
        j += 1
      j = 0
      i += 1
    return False
    
  def resetBoard(self):
    self.field = self.newField()
    self.winState = self.winType["none"]
    self.currentTurn = True
    self.path = []
    
  def newField(self):
    self.field = [[int((1 + i + self.width * j)) for i in range(self.width)]
                  for j in range(self.width)]
    return self.field

  def _getBoardSize(self):
    #in init, replace width from const to self.getBoardSize()
    while (True):
      try:
        boardSize = int(input("board square size? 3 is best, odd only: "))
        if (boardSize % 2 == 1):
          break
      except:
        continue
    #return boardSize #have some issues with larger boards, gotta fix and then this is possible
    return boardSize
```

and just in case, this is main.py

```
#V3 might be working better then v2. All changes are in the build frontier

import sys, os, time

from ai import *
from board import *


# minimax version

#features for the future:
#     - use pygaem to display (might not work on person running code's computer)
#     - have winning image sequence
#     - when there are no possible moves that can win, tie 


class TicTacToeGame:
  validationInputs = {
    "y": True,
    "yes": True,
    "sure": True,
    "of course": True,
    "definatly": True,
    "affirmative": True,
    "yup": True,
    "ya": True,
    "yuh": True,
    "certainly": True,
    "n": False,
    "no": False,
    "nope": False,
    "nadda": False,
    "never": False,
  }
 
  def __init__(self):
    self.board = c_board(True,[],0,[],True)
    print("press anything to start a game")
    input("> ")
    self.getPlayMode()
    self.startGame()
  
  def startGame(self):
    #os.system("clear")
    
    self.board.resetBoard()

    self.playGame()

  
  def playGame(self):
    endGameStates = [c_board.winType["x"],c_board.winType["o"],c_board.winType["tie"]]
    self.display()
    if (self.board.winState in endGameStates):
    
      valid = False
      while (not valid):
        try:
          print(" continue on same game mode:       1")
          print(" try playing a different gamemode: 2")
          try:
            answer = int(input(">"))
          except:
            raise Exception("not a number")
          if (answer == 2):
            valid = True
            self.getPlayMode()
          elif (answer == 1):
            valid = True
          else:
            valid = False
            raise Exception("answer is not 1 or 2")
        except Exception as e:
          print(e)
     # os.system("clear")
      self.startGame()
    elif(self.board.winState == c_board.winType["none"]):
      if (self.playAi == False):
        self.playerMark()
      else:
        if (self.playerFirst == self.board.currentTurn):
          print("player")
          self.playerMark()
        else:
          print("ai")

          aiMove = aiPlayer(self.board.field,self.board.currentTurn,self.playerFirst,self.board.width,[],self.aiMode).getMove()
          print('aiMove is', aiMove)
          
          self.board.fillBoard(aiMove)

      self.board.winState = self.board.evaluatePosition()
      print("wS: ",self.board.winState)
      self.playGame()
  
  
  def printWinner(self):
    if (self.playAi):
      if((self.playerFirst == self.board.currentTurn)):
        print("you win")
      else:
        print("ai wins")
    elif(not self.playAi):
      if(self.board.currentTurn):
        print("p1 wins")
      else:
        print("p2 wins")
 
  def display(self):
    #os.system("clear")
    self.board.printBoard()
    print(self.board.path)
    if(self.board.winState == c_board.winType["tie"]):
      print("tie")
    elif(self.board.winState == c_board.winType["x"] or self.board.winState == c_board.winType["o"]):
      self.board.currentTurn = not self.board.currentTurn
      self.printWinner()
      self.board.newField()
  
 
  def playerMark(self):  #either x or o
    self.foundTile = False
    valid = False
    while(not valid):
      try:
        answer = input("tileNum: ")
        if(answer == "e"):
          self.resetScreen()
          self.board.newField()
          break
          
        tileNum = int(answer)
        for row in self.board.field:
          for val in row:
            if val == tileNum:
              valid = True
        
        if(not valid):
          raise Exception("no tile found")
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
      self.board.fillBoard(tileNum)
    
  def resetScreen(self):
    while(True):
      print("sit here to relax")
      time.sleep(1)
      print("we are zen")
      time.sleep(1)
      print("press enter to start a new game")
      time.sleep(1)
      print("but take your time")
      input(">")
      self.startGame()
   
    
  def getPlayMode(self):
    self.board.resetBoard()
    allValid = False
    while (allValid == False):
      try:
        print("play against AI? y/n")
        answer = input("> ").lower().strip()

        if (answer not in self.validationInputs):
          raise Exception("not a valid input")

        self.playAi = self.validationInputs[answer]
        if (not self.playAi):
          allValid = True
          break

        
        print("AI Mode: 1) next!")
        print("         2) random!")
        print("         3) Smart")
        answer = input(">").strip()
        if(answer not in ["1","2","3"]):
          raise Exception("not a valid input")
        self.aiMode = int(answer)
        
        print("play first? y/n")
        answer = input("> ").lower().strip()
        if (answer not in self.validationInputs):
          raise Exception("not a valid input")

        self.playerFirst = self.validationInputs[answer]
        allValid = True
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def main():
  global game
  game = TicTacToeGame()
  
main()
```

and(probibally unnessisary) this is the entire computer player code instead of what I had selected to show:

```
from board import *
import random

global overallFrontier
overallFrontier = []

global listOfAiPlayers
listOfAiPlayers = []

class aiPlayer:
  def __init__(self, field, currentTurn,firstPlayer,width,path,aiMode):
    self.board = c_board(False,field,width,path,currentTurn)
    self.mode = aiMode
    self.firstPlayer = firstPlayer
    overallFrontier = []
     
  def getFirstOpenSpotFromFieldForBasicCompPlayer(self):
    for row in self.board.field:
      for item in row:
        if(item not in ["x","o"]):
          return item
  def playRandomMove(self):
    listOfSpaces = []
    for row in self.board.field:
      for item in row:
        if(item not in ["x","o"]):
          listOfSpaces.append(item)
    if(len(listOfSpaces)>0):
      return random.choice(listOfSpaces)
    else:
      return
  
  def getMove(self):
    if(self.mode == 1):
      self.bestTileNum = self.getFirstOpenSpotFromFieldForBasicCompPlayer()
    if(self.mode == 2):
      self.bestTileNum = self.playRandomMove()
    if(self.mode == 3):
      self.bestTileNum = self.smartSearchGetMove()
    print("getMove: ", self.bestTileNum)
    print("the game board this sees")
    self.board.printBoard()
    #return 
    return self.bestTileNum #int
    #TODO: after the best case is found, return the first number that leads down that case
  
  def smartSearchGetMove(self): 
    recurse_buildFrontier(self.board.field,self.board.width,self.board.path,self.board.currentTurn,0)

    print(" ***** ")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    for board in overallFrontier:
      
      print(board)

      print(" ")
      print(" ")
      print(" ")
    print(" ***** ")
    
    return self.playRandomMove()
    
    """for ai in listOfAiPlayers:
      print("ai address: ", ai)
      
    print("Final frontier: ")
    
    for board in overallFrontier:
      board.printBoard()
      
    if(not self.board.currentTurn):
      print("Optimize for X")
      
    else:
      print("Optimize for O")
"""

    #TODO: optimizedBoard.path
   

class recurse_buildFrontier:
  def __init__(self,field,width,path,currentTurn,iteration):
    print("RecurseAI: ", iteration)
    self.board = c_board(False,field,width,path,currentTurn)
    self.iteration = iteration
    self.buildFrontier()
  def buildFrontier(self):  
    print("================ BuildFrontierCall =====================")
    print("iteration: ", self.iteration + 1)
    print("frontier: ", overallFrontier)

    for row in self.board.field:
      for spot in row:
        if(spot in range(self.board.width * self.board.width) and spot not in self.board.path):#the not path bit is implied, just for clarity its written
          spotFrontierBoard = c_board(False,self.board.field,self.board.width,self.board.path,not self.board.currentTurn)
          spotFrontierBoard.fillBoard(spot)
          
          print("-- spot: ", spot)
          print("! spotFrontierBoard print !")
          spotFrontierBoard.printBoard()
          print("! self board print !")
          self.board.printBoard()

          spotFrontierBoard.evaluatePosition()
          evaluate = spotFrontierBoard.winState
          evaluatePrinter = "X" if evaluate == c_board.winType["x"] else "O" if evaluate == c_board.winType["o"] else "TIE" if evaluate == c_board.winType["tie"] else "none" if evaluate == c_board.winType["none"] else "evaluate error"
          print("evaluate: ",evaluatePrinter )
          if (evaluate in [c_board.winType["x"],c_board.winType["o"],c_board.winType["tie"]]):
            overallFrontier.append(spotFrontierBoard)
          else:
            recurse_buildFrontier(spotFrontierBoard.field,self.board.width,spotFrontierBoard.path,not self.board.currentTurn,self.iteration+1).buildFrontier()

    print("++++++++++ END BuildFrontierCall +++++++++++")
```

This screenshot shows the problem in the [debug output where each board has a unique id, which increments each time a new board object is created. We can see that the board of the first iteration of the search algorighm (referenced by self.board) is overwritten by the board that is created when exploring paths(referenced as iterationBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2bPA.png)

which is displayed by this section of code in the recurse_buildFrontier class:

[code that prints showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUgef.png)

The self.board should look like the the move before the iteration board, as iteration board is exploring every open spot in self.board. Iteration board takes a single spot and fills it, yet both print out the same thing.

The fillBoard function which is called and makes this change only references self.field

```
def fillBoard(self,tile):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for column in self.field:
      for val in column:
        if (val == tile):
          self.field[i][j] = ("x" if (self.currentTurn == self.firstPlayer) else "o")
          self.currentTurn = not self.currentTurn
          self.path.append(tile)
          return self.field
        j += 1
      j = 0
      i += 1
    return False
```

The code works for the picknextmove and pickrandommove.
Another demonstration of the weirdness:
[this is what self.board looks like when aiPlayer class is initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lS7u.png)
[this is the same self.board which is made when aiPlayer class is initiated. Here, it is printed after the recurse_buildFrontier call receives. It should look the same, as I never change it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbfWu.png)

Comment: Please fix the indentation.  For example, `def getMove()` is not indented underneath the `aiPlayer` class, when it seems like it should be.

Comment: Also, please show `c_board`.  Is that a class?  A function?

Comment: Class variables are by definition shared across the entire class.  If `c_board` saves its state in class variables, you effectively only ever have one board.  Change it to use instance variables.

Comment: If you want to ask a question *about* using Stack Overflow, you can do that on https://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: "Sorry about the weird indenting, I can't hit tab".  Just paste your code between triple-backtick marks or highlight and hit the `{}` (format code) button.

Comment: @Samwise thank you, the board's state is set up in init and stored under self.varName, ie self.field(numbers, X, O of the game board), self.path(order of moves to get to that moves),  etc. My understanding was that self. makes a separate variables for each instance of the class, and wouldn't be overwritten. Do you know any other possible spots for the issue? Thank you again!

Comment: @MarkTolonen thank you, I tried to do the {} at the top, but it indented the code too much or not enough. Do you have anything I could google to figure out the issue better?

Comment: @SorinJayaweera a simpler way to indent is putting three backticks before and three after your code